# What does "vr:canonical" mean?

Tags: html, meta

What namespace/scheme/whatever does this "vr:canonical" come from?

```
<meta property="vr:canonical" content="URL_FROM_OTHER_PAGE" />
```

(edit: I know canonical links, just curious about that "vr:" thing)

Comment: canonical link makes indexing bots to understand that two or more pages is same. https://moz.com/blog/canonical-url-tag-the-most-important-advancement-in-seo-practices-since-sitemaps

Comment: OP is probably wondering more about the `vr:` part.

Comment: Is there a corresponding namespace attribute on the html element?

Comment: No. This is the only time in the document where this namespace occurs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After analyzing the page (and the code of its used trackers and counters and advertising scripts), this seems to be a property used by an advertising tool named "VisualRevenue", a product by the Company [Outbrain](http://www.outbrain.com/).

Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score -2):

For example:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://moz.com/blog" />
```

This would tell Google that the page in question should be treated as though it were a copy of the URL above and that all of the link & content metrics the engines apply should technically flow back to that URL.

The Canonical URL tag attribute is similar in many ways to a **301** redirect from an SEO perspective. In essence, you're telling the engines that multiple pages should be considered as one (which a 301 does), without actually redirecting visitors to the new URL

Comment: As I said: I know canonical links. But the question here is about that "vr:" Namespace.